# Copy cell value to a different worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets in it. Say `Book1`, `Book2`, `Book3` etc. 
I want to copy the value of `Book1` Cell D5 into `Book2` Cell E3.

What is the formula for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking VBA code or simply the Excel formula? If the latter, just select cell E3 in Book2 and type `=Book1!D5`. If you're asking for VBA code, I don't know...

[image]